# If $f$ and $g$ both satisfy Cauchy Riemann equations at point $z$, prove $f+g$ and $fg$ satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

So if $f=u+iv$, and $g=m+in$. Trying to prove $fg$ follows the Cauchy Riemann equations: I got $fg=(mu-nv)+i(nu+mv)$, letting $a=mu-nv$ and letting $b=nu+mv$, I differentiated $a$ and $b$, by $x$ and $y$ but I can't equate the differentials so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Hint: you don't need to differentiate anything at all. You already know that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$, and that $\frac{\partial m}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial n}{\partial y}$, and you know that (partial) differentiation is a linear map.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by (partial) differentiation is a linear map.

Comment: The set of all differentiable functions $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. The maps $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ are linear maps from that vector space to $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\frac{\partial(mu-nv)}{\partial x}&=\frac{\partial m}{\partial x}u+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}m-\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}v-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}n\\&=\frac{\partial n}{\partial y}u+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}m+\frac{\partial m}{\partial y}v+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}n\\&=\frac{\partial n}{\partial y}u+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}n+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}m+\frac{\partial m}{\partial y}v\\&=\frac{\partial(nu+mv)}{\partial y}.\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't understand how the first line is equal to the second line, as the first line is differentiated with respect x an the third line is differentiated with respect to y. Also, the first line of the 3rd and 4th terms are negative whereas there are no negatives on the 2nd line.

Comment: I am assuming that $f$ and $g$ satisfy the Cauchy-RIemann equations. Therefore, $\frac{\partial m}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial n}{\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial m}{\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$, and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

Comment: I see, thank you for that. Do I use the same process for f+g?

Comment: Sure. It's even simpler in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much.